# Detect and extract Pivot tables from xls files using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to determine if a xls file has Pivot tables and then if it does to extract the data using POI.  I know there are other libraries which can do this such as Aspose but I need to use POI.

xlsx files are supported but POI doesn't seem to support xls.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272
   ;
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-from-an-excel-file-using-poi.html

Comment: Thank you, but neither of those examples have anything to do with Pivot tables which was the main point of the question.  I already know how to read normal data just not Pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

I aparently didn't RTFM.
See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html

> Pivot Tables - 
>   HSSF doesn't have support for reading or creating Pivot tables. XSSF has limited support for creating Pivot Tables, and very limited read/change support.